# How to pass the name of the item in a listview to another form in Xamarin

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have made a xamarin cross platform application that returns a list of items from web api.
the xaml code looks like this:

```
    <ViewModels:ItemViewModel/>

</ContentPage.BindingContext>

<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsList}"

          HasUnevenRows="True" 
          x:Name="lstItems"
         ItemTapped="LstItems_OnItemTapped">



    <ListView.ItemTemplate>

        <DataTemplate>

            <ViewCell>

                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">

                    <Label Text="{Binding ItemCode}" x:Name="lblItemCode" FontSize="Medium" TextColor="Blue"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding ItemDesc}" FontSize="Medium" TextColor="Blue"/>


                </StackLayout>

            </ViewCell>

        </DataTemplate>

    </ListView.ItemTemplate>

</ListView>
```

I need to pass the ItemCode as a parameter to the next page.
How can i do that? What do i write in the xaml page and what do i write in the code behind?
Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

in your code behind

```
protected void LstItems_OnItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs args) {
  var item = (MyItemClass) args.Item;
  var newpage = new MyNextPage(item.ItemCode);
  Navigation.PushAsync(newpage);
}
```

Comment: Hey!.. This is a dynamic list of items from the web api. And I need to pass the itemcode of the item that has been clicked on the listview. Will your code work for that?

Comment: it should, did you try it?

Comment: yes i did. not working. can u suggest some other method of doing this please?

Comment: What does "not working" mean?  Where specifically is it failing?  Is the event getting called?  Is the appropriate item being retrieved from the list?  Is your page stack contained within a NavigationPage already?

Comment: it is not recogonizing the args keyword and showing an error. I have written this code: private async void LstItems_OnItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)

        {
         
            var ItemCodeParam = sender as Item;

            if (ItemCodeParam != null)
            {
                var ItemCode = ItemCodeParam.ItemCode;

                await Navigation.PushAsync(newDetailItemPage(ItemCode.ToString()))

But here the navigation just does not happen.

Comment: "an error" - what specifically is the error?  And the code you wrote is significantly different than what I suggested.  You are trying to cast sender as Item, when sender is ListView.  e.Item will contain the specific data element that list item is bound to.